# How can I change the language of Windows 7 to English?

Tags: windows-7, windows, language

I have a German edition of Windows 7 and want to change its language to English.

Does anyone know how to do this?

P.s. I have a home version of windows (not professional or ultimate) :)

P.s.s. I can't manage to get any lb.cab file, can any1 also provide a link to that?

Answer (score 15):

You must have Ultimate or Enterprise edition to go from German to English, otherwise you must buy an English version of Windows 7 and re-install the Operating System.

1. Start -> All Programs --> Windows Update --> Optional Updates.
2. Open optional Updates and go to the section Windows 7 Language Packs.
3. Tick the Language Pack you want and hit OK
4. Proceed with Install Updates
5. Depiction of Windows 7 downloading a Language Pack
6. Automatic install initiated after download

[How to change the Windows 7 Display Language](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Install-or-change-a-display-language):

1. Go to Start -> Control Panel -> Clock, Language, and Region / Change the display language
2. Switch the display language in the Choose a display language dropdown menu.
3. Click OK
4. Log off for the changes to take effect (This will affect only the user profile under which you are currently logged on).

[Source of Information](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/downloads/install-languages-with-windows-update)

[More Information](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/downloads/languages)

---

Here's an [English tutorial](http://mark.ossdl.de/2009/08/change-mui-language-pack-in-windows-7-home-and-professional/) and a [German tutorial](http://www.hitech-blog.com/software/windows-7-home-und-professional-language-pack-installieren/).

Comment: Available only on Enterprise/Ultimate, btw.

Comment: And only on the English version of Windows :)

Comment: I'm not sure those links should be allowed. Might go against EULA. @slhck

Comment: @Sathya Yes — wasn't too sure either. Feel free to remove.

Comment: I have a home version of windows :)

Comment: Such a basic OS feature requires Ultimate, shame MS...

Comment: You said "You must have Ultimate or Enterprise edition to go from German to English, otherwise you must buy an English version of Windows 7 and re-install the Operating System." Do you know if this applies to Windows 10 too? Many thanks!

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem and I followed what is here:

http://mark.ossdl.de/2009/08/change-mui-language-pack-in-windows-7-home-and-professional/

> you will have to get the appropriate “lp.cab”, i.e. from the Language Pack DVD. Then, type this in a command prompt as Administrator (change path and language code appropriately):
>
> 1. **dism /online /add-package /packagepath:D:\langpacks\en-us\lp.cab**
> 2. **bcdedit /set {current} locale en-US**
> 3. **bcdboot %WinDir% /l en-US**
>
> After that, remove the registry folder **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\MUI\UILanguages\de-DE**.
>
> Reboot
>
> If you get this error: An error occured trying to open d:\en-us\langpacks\lp.cab Error:0×80070003. The System cannot find the path specified
>
> **copy the lp.cab to C:\ (the root directory) and run dism from there.**
>
> The command line shell must be run as Administrator.

And it worked

Comment: Do you happen to have a link to a lb.cab file? I can't find one anywhere

Comment: After applying this Windows Update may stop working, if it happens, reinstall windows update agent http://support.microsoft.com/kb/949104

Answer (score 7):

I changed the display language of a Windows in Korean (Windows 7 Home Premium SP1 x32 "K") to English using [Vistalizator](http://www.froggie.sk/en/download.html)  ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20170430024749/http://www.froggie.sk/en/download.html)) (free, straightforward to use, the website contains required Microsoft updates as well as language packs):

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

It may ask for some Windows updates:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Vistalizator](http://www.froggie.sk/en/index.html):

> Did you buy a Windows laptop from abroad and want it to talk to you in
>   your mother tongue?
>
> Try Vistalizator - this tool allows you to change display language in
>   Windows editions other than (officially supported) Ultimate, like
>   Starter, Home Basic, Home Premium and Business/Professional.
>
> Vistalizator overrides the limit of one MUI language on non-Ultimate
>   Windows editions.

Answer (score -1):

I know this question is for windows 7, but it's one of the top hits on google. On Windows 10 this can be done on all variants (I just tested this on the pro version, but have read it should work on the Home edition too). The following works to change the language of one user, and I'm not sure how to do it for the whole OS (so even the login screen is in another language)

- Press Win + i
- Select *Time and Language*
- Go in *Region & Language*
- Add the language of your choice
- Click on new language and an *Options* button appears
- Click on the button to download the *Language Pack*
- Go back to the previous screen (where you can see all the installed languages)
- Click on the new language again and click on *Set as default*

The next time you log in, windows will be in the new language!